# How do I have my widgets in a Sidebar for my http://localhost/wordpress/

Tags: theme-options, localhost

I have installed wordpress version 5.7.1 with MAMP 6.3 on my MacOS laptop.

However on localhost/wordpress, I do not like the way the Twenty Twenty-one theme is set out because under appearance, I had to create a a customised widget, which included a Meta Widget for a Log in.

**The problem is that I have to scroll down the page to find the Log in as can be seen below.**

[image: Wordpress Localhost Top of Page]
[image: Wordpress Localhost Login bottom of Page]

**How do I have all these Widgets (Search bar, Meta, Recent Posts, Recent Comments, Archives and Categories) in a Sidebar, so that they are displayed below each other  ?**

When I installed Wordpress on my older Windows laptop, it had a sidebar, as can be seen below, so this is ideally how I would like to have it.

[image: WAMP Wordpress Localhost Theme with Sidebar]

Comment: You just need to pick a theme that has the layout you want. This is not the place to ask for recommendations though. This is a development stack exchange. Start by going to Themes > Add New and looking for one that suits you.

Comment: I don't think you are quite understanding my question.

I want to keep the twenty twenty-one theme I have and have the widgets in a sidebar ?
Is it possible to have the widgets in a sidebar ?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Where should this post go, if this forum is for development questions ?
I haven't seen much on how how you can put a group of widgets in a sidebar.

I just want to have my twenty twenty-one theme set out better, like when I installed wordpress on WAMP for my older laptop .
I did not have to adjust the theme and it is setout a lot better than the twenty twenty-one theme.

Comment: It’s just not how twenty twenty one is designed. Why not just use the other theme if you prefer it? There isn’t a standard option to add a sidebar to any arbitrary theme. It needs to be designed for it. Support questions are best asked at the wordpress.org support forums. Also search the theme directory, someone may have made a child theme of twenty twenty one that has a sidebar.